# Images not showing up on drupal test site

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

I have successfully installed CKeditor and am attempting to link some images. After many errors I got the path right but once saved the page still ends up blank and when going back to administer the basic page the image is no longer there nor a broken image link...? I put the image file in an images folder inside the files folder. I did notice that the image shows up in the wsiwyg editor when properly linked but still no luck.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your drupal installation is in a subfolder (eg. http://localhost/drupal/) then the images won't work as they reference the root (`/`), which is in fact `localhost` (i.e. not where the images are).

To fix it, edit `sites/default/settings.php`, uncomment the `$base_url =` statement and change it to eg. `$base_url = 'http://localhost/drupal/';`

Answer (score 0):

Also, check the Text Format you're using to create your content.  Some Text Formats filter certain HTML tags causing them to not show up.  This might give you more info: http://www.lullabot.com/articles/drupal-input-formats-and-filters

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The URL for the image that I was using was an absolute URL for another web site and the image would show up in the editor, but not in the final post.

The problem for me was that the "Text Format" was set to "Filtered HTML" instead of "Full HTML". From what I understand, "Filtered HTML" disallows the use of certain HTML tags.

**NOTE**: Permissions have to be set to use the "Full HTML" option. Although, an Administrator should be able to use it by default.

There is a page about the text formatting on the Drupal site:
http://drupal.org/node/213156

According to the page, disallowed tags should have been escaped (shown as HTML). Although, for me, they were removed. Also, I checked the "Configuration > Content authoring > Text formats" section and, for Drupal 7, it appears that IMG tags can be used, but there is a limit on how many characters are usable in an IMG tag.

I know this response is quite late, but it might be of help to other people having this problem.